# JOML (with LWJGL) - Get rotation matrix from rx, ry, and rz values?

Tags: java, matrix, lwjgl

I've been using LWJGL with JOML added on as a means of creating a 3D game engine.
I have come across a problem since I have been loosely following a tutorial by Jeffrey ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCc7d1TgdhIiEjIeJkUJIkPw)), but I have been using the JOML library instead of the mini math library he created. I have made a **Transform** class, which has been copied from Jeffrey's math library, and I have been translating it to use JOML:

```
import org.joml.Matrix4f;
import org.joml.Vector3f;

public class Transform {
    public static Matrix4f getPerspectiveProjection(float fov, int width, int height, float zNear, float zFar) {
        return new Matrix4f().setPerspective(fov, width / height, zNear, zFar);
    }

    public static Matrix4f getTransformation(Vector3f translation, float rx, float ry, float rz, float scale) {
        Matrix4f translationMatrix = new Matrix4f().setTranslation(translation);

        // The first problem:
        Matrix4f rotationMatrix = new Matrix4f().getRotation(rx, ry, rz);

        Matrix4f scaleMatrix = new Matrix4f().initScale(scale);

        return translationMatrix.mul(rotationMatrix.mul(scaleMatrix));
    }

    public static Matrix4f getViewMatrix(Camera camera) {
        Vector3f pos = camera.getPosition();

        Matrix4f translationMatrix = new Matrix4f().setTranslation(-pos.x, -pos.y, -pos.z);
        Matrix4f rotationMatrix = new Matrix4f().initRotation(camera.getForward(), camera.getUp());

        return rotationMatrix.mul(translationMatrix);
    }
}
```

From the JOML documentation, all I can find is using [Matrix4f.getRotation](https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Matrix4f.html#getRotation-org.joml.AxisAngle4f-) with **AxisAngle4f**.

The crux of the matter is, how do I translate the **rx**, **ry**, and **rz** angles into an **AxisAngle4f**?

Answer (score 1):

Please very carefully and thoroughly read the JavaDocs of the JOML methods. `Matrix4f.getRotation()` retrieves the rotational part of the (affine) matrix and converts that rotation to an axis-angle representing the identical rotation. That method does not *create*/*build* a rotation matrix from three Euler angles.

So, to state/rephrase your question very precisely:
"How do I build an affine 4x4 matrix representing a 3D rotation given three Euler angles (i.e. angles around the X, Y and Z axes, respectively), applying rotations in the order X, then Y and then Z?"

And the answer to that is: `Matrix4f.rotationXYZ()` or the post-multiplying `Matrix4f.rotateXYZ()`.
If you need a different rotation order, you can also look at the other "swizzled" rotationYXZ/ZYX and rotateYXZ/ZYX methods, or even apply three calls to `Matrix4f.rotate()` given the rotation axis and angle.

I recommend you also consult the Wiki on the GitHub project and the sources of the joml-lwjgl3-demos project on GitHub.